# How to create a list of dates?

Tags: apex, list

I am having trouble to add dates into the list. I tried the following.

```
//Create a list of medicine expiry dates
public class MedExpiry {
    List<Date> ExpDate = new List<Date>();
    ExpDate.add('2016-4-28');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to construct a `Date` instance.

```
Date someDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 4, 28);
List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
dates.add(someDate);
```

Alternatively, you can construct a list with delineated elements if you use curly braces (`{}`) instead of parentheses (`()`).

```
List<Date> dates = new List<Date> { someDate };
```